# SQL Join Query - two FK, one field

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've got a small issue that I'm not sure how to resolve - I've never encountered it before. I'm using MS SQL and have a SQL JOIN query that queries two tables - Insurance and Creditors. The insurance table holds all the policy details, while the Creditor table holds the company details (Insurance Company/Broker name etc).

The Insurance table holds two foreign keys named CreditorID and BrokerID. Both of these foreign keys relate to the same field, being the CreditorID field in the Creditor table (because some creditors are both insurance companies AND insurance brokers). What I'm not sure of is how to write the query.

E.g. The Insurance table might look something like this:

```
lInsuranceID   lCreditorID  lBrokerID  mLastPremium  dDatePaid  sPolicyNumber
1              1            null       1000.00       28/03/2014 12345
2              14           1          2000.00       17/03/2014 67891
```

And the Creditor table might look something like this:

```
lCreditorID   sCreditorName
1             Frank's Insurance COMPANY
14            Frank's Insurance BROKER
```

So the issue is, when I retrieve the information for a particular property, I need to pull info from the Creditor table twice - once with Insurance.CreditorID = Creditor.CreditorID and again with Insurance.CreditorID = Creditor.BrokerID.

But I don't know how to do that in one join. I tried this, but it didn't work (I get an error that says "Creditor.sCreditorName" could not be bound:

```
 SELECT Insurance.sPolicyNumber,
        Insurance.dDatePaid,
        Insurance.dRenewal,
        Insurance.mLastPremium,
        Creditor.sCreditorName
   FROM Insurance
        INNER JOIN Creditor cred ON Insurance.lCreditorID = cred.lCreditorID
        INNER JOIN Creditor cred1 ON Insurance.lBrokerID = cred1.lCreditorID
  WHERE Insurance.lOwnersCorporationID = '1'
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
Ok thanks for all the tips, peeps. I amended the query to look like this and it appears to be working (I'm such a JOIN noob. Even though it works, I'm not sure why)

```
SELECT Insurance.sPolicyNumber, Insurance.dDatePaid, Insurance.dRenewal, Insurance.mLastPremium, cred.sCreditorName as Company, cred1.sCreditorName as Broker
FROM Insurance
LEFT JOIN Creditor cred ON Insurance.lCreditorID = cred.lCreditorID
LEFT JOIN Creditor cred1 ON Insurance.lBrokerID = cred1.lCreditorID
WHERE Insurance.lOwnersCorporationID = '1'
```

Comment: Oh and just to clarify, the reason I need to query both fields is that sometimes a property is insured with "Fred's Insurance Company" but is actually brokered by "Dude's Brokerage Firm". So I need both fields to ensure all information is there.
AND, I didn't design this database, nor can I amend the design one iota as other systems rely on its structure as it already is.

Comment: The reason `Creditor.sCreditorName` can't be bound is because you have not used Creditor as an alias - you have cred and `cred1` so SQL has no idea which table it belongs to (even though it's the same table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the table alias in the SELECT expression list:

```
 SELECT i.sPolicyNumber,
        i.dDatePaid,
        i.dRenewal,
        i.mLastPremium,
        c.sCreditorName,
        b.sCreditorName
   FROM Insurance i
        LEFT JOIN Creditor  c ON c.lCreditorID = i.lCreditorID
        LEFT JOIN Creditor  b ON b.lCreditorID = i.lBrokerID
  WHERE Insurance.lOwnersCorporationID = '1'
```

Notice that I switched to LEFT OUTER JOINs. That is because you have shown that the referencing values may be NULLable. If you don't use OUTER JOINs you will loose rows from the Insurance table, which I think is undesirable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this

```
 SELECT Insurance.sPolicyNumber,
        Insurance.dDatePaid,
        Insurance.dRenewal,
        Insurance.mLastPremium,
        cred.sCreditorName AS Creditor,
        cred1.sCreditorName AS Broker
   FROM Insurance
        INNER JOIN Creditor cred ON Insurance.lCreditorID = cred.lCreditorID
        INNER JOIN Creditor cred1 ON Insurance.lBrokerID = cred1.lCreditorID
  WHERE Insurance.lOwnersCorporationID = '1'
```

I've added a [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23d1c/3) to demonstrate (minus the columns in the select statement that don't exist in the example tables). This uses your original query but see below for another example with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out below, a `LEFT JOIN` would be useful so you do not filter out rows where `BrokerID` is `NULL`. Updated example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23d1c/5) to show this too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a left join might help? Since you might not have a Broker ID in all instances.

```
 SELECT Insurance.sPolicyNumber,
        Insurance.dDatePaid,
        Insurance.dRenewal,
        Insurance.mLastPremium,
        Creditor.sCreditorName
   FROM Insurance
        INNER JOIN Creditor cred ON Insurance.lCreditorID = cred.lCreditorID
         LEFT JOIN Creditor cred1 ON Insurance.lBrokerID = cred1.lCreditorID
  WHERE Insurance.lOwnersCorporationID = '1'
```

Comment: Why the downvote? @Matt is right that a `LEFT JOIN` is probably needed in this case where the example data shows a `NULL` in BrokerID as otherwise that row will be filtered out and the OP probably doesn't realise since their query doesn't work at all currently.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This one didn't quite work (couldn't bind Creditor.sCreditorName), but I got it to work by doing
    SELECT
    ....
    Insurance.mLastPremium, cred.sCreditorName, cred1.sCreditorName
    .... etc

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Insurance.sPolicyNumber,
        Insurance.dDatePaid,
        Insurance.dRenewal, 
        Insurance.mLastPremium, 
        -- the changed columns
        cred.sCreditorName AS CREDITOR,
        cred1.sCreditorName AS BROKER,  
   FROM Insurance
        INNER JOIN Creditor cred ON Insurance.lCreditorID = cred.lCreditorID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Creditor cred1 ON Insurance.lBrokerID = cred1.lCreditorID
  WHERE Insurance.lOwnersCorporationID = '1'
```

As you are referreing to the table using Alias (cred and cred1) you have to use the alias name in column listing

Answer (score 0):

In you original query, you are refer "Creditor.sCreditorName", however you are using the alias cred in the join.

also, you are using inner joins, which may lead out some entries, in case the FK is null. Eg your entry with lInsuranceID = 1 would be missed out.

A correct query could be

```
 SELECT ins.sPolicyNumber,
        ins.dDatePaid,
        ins.dRenewal,
        ins.mLastPremium,
        cred.sCreditorName as CreditorName,
        brok.sCreditorName as BrokerName
   FROM Insurance ins
        LEFT JOIN Creditor cred ON ins.lCreditorID = cred.lCreditorID
        LEFT JOIN Creditor brok ON ins.lBrokerID = brok.lCreditorID
  WHERE ins.lOwnersCorporationID = '1'
```

Some testing in MSSQL:

```
declare @Insurance table
(
    lInsuranceID int,
    lCreditorID  int,
    lBrokerID  int,
    mLastPremium  money,
    dDatePaid  date,
    sPolicyNumber int
)

 INSERT INTO @Insurance
        (lInsuranceID, lCreditorID, lBrokerID, mLastPremium, dDatePaid,
         sPolicyNumber)
 SELECT 1, 1, null, 1000.00, '2014-03-28', 12345
  UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 14, 1, 2000.00, '2014-03-17', 67891

declare @Creditor table
(
    lCreditorID int,
    sCreditorName varchar(64)
)

 INSERT INTO @Creditor
        (lCreditorID, sCreditorName)
 SELECT 1, 'Frank''s Insurance COMPANY'
  UNION ALL
 SELECT 14, 'Frank''s Insurance BROKER'


 SELECT ins.sPolicyNumber,
        ins.dDatePaid,
        ins.mLastPremium,
        brok.sCreditorName as BrokerName,
        cred.sCreditorName as CreditorName
   FROM @Insurance ins
        LEFT JOIN @Creditor cred on cred.lCreditorID = ins.lCreditorID
        LEFT JOIN @Creditor brok on brok.lCreditorID = ins.lBrokerID
```